# Javascript error after minification

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC Bundling and Minification and Angular frontend. Without minification, everything works fine but with debug set to false and with minification on I get this angular error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=n

```
    Unknown provider: n
```

Comment: You should use magnification syntax for this. so pass array of all services and other to function.

Answer (score 0):

You should use magnification syntax for this. so pass array of all services and other to function. like to this as a sample:

```
   app.controller("Main",["$scope","otherService",function($scope,otherService){

    }]);
```